# Unable to get date/time from XML - Strange value in source

Tags: php, xml, date

I'm just starting with php, but this is a thing I can't figure out.
I browsed the internet / stack / other forums, but for now I don't have any clue.

The date format is something I can't understand / recognize at all:

```
<datum>1491976626</datum>
<datum>1491894573</datum>
<datum>1491734853</datum>
<datum>1491680837</datum>
<datum>1491671357</datum>
```

Here's the link to the XML: [Link](http://mobiliteit.klantenvertellen.nl/xml/autodrome-grassere)

When you check the 'datum' node, you'll see it.
As an example (compared to the output on this [site](https://mobiliteit.klantenvertellen.nl/beoordelingen/autodrome-grassere/1183))

```
Value: 1491734853
= Date: 09-04-2017

Value: 1491671357
= Date: 08-04-2017

Value: 1491463926
= Date: 06-04-2017
```

Anyone of you guys / guru's have an idea how to get this working? Is there a default (sort of) algoritm for this or something I don't know of?

Thank you very much for thinking with me :)

Comment: its unix time, try `$result=date('Y-m-d h:i:s',1491734853);` it will give desired date

Comment: Is it you want?

Comment: Please check my reply below :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the job, but I'm unable to get it to show..

This is the PHP code I have so far:

```
<?php
foreach ($xml->beoordelingen->beoordeling as $beoordelingenoverzicht) { 

    echo "<div class='containerbeoordeling'><div class='hoofd'>";
    foreach($beoordelingenoverzicht->voornaam as $label => $voornaam) {
    echo "<div class='naam'><span id='label'>Naam</span><span id='voornaam'>{$voornaam}</span>"; }

    foreach($beoordelingenoverzicht->achternaam as $label => $achternaam) {
        echo "<span id='achternaam'> {$achternaam}</span></div>";
    }
    foreach($beoordelingenoverzicht->datum as $label => $datum) {
        $datumnew = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$datum);
        echo "<div class='datum'><span id='label'>{$label}</span><span id='datum'>{$datumnew}</span></div></div>";
    }
    foreach($beoordelingenoverzicht->beschrijving as $label => $beschrijving) {
        echo "<div class='beschrijving'>{$beschrijving}</div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
} 
?>
```

I wouldn't be surprised if I implemented it totally wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

It suppose it's just a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), one of the most ubiquitous date formats in computer science. Many PHP date functions support it natively, e.g. [date()](http://php.net/date):

```
var_dump(date('r', 1491734853));
//  string(31) "Sun, 09 Apr 2017 12:47:33 +0200"
```

> The optional `timestamp` parameter is an integer Unix timestamp that
>   defaults to the current local time if a timestamp is not given. In
>   other words, it defaults to the value of time().